# Showing a group is isomorphic to a group with known presentation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation

Let $H$ be a group with presentation $\langle h_1, \dots, h_n \mid r_1 = \dots = r_m = 1\rangle$. If there are $g_1, \dots, g_n \in G$ which satisfy the relations $r_1, \dots, r_m$, when is $\varphi : H \to G$ generated by $\varphi(h_i) = g_i$ an isomorphism? In particular, is there an effective way to check that the elements $g_i$ don't satisfy any additional relations?

Comment: By Von Dyck's theorem, such a map is surjective onto $\langle g_1,\cdots,g_n\rangle$. If $G\neq\langle g_1,\cdots,g_n\rangle$, then certainly $\varphi$ cannot be an isomorphism. On the other hand, if $G=\langle g_1,\cdots,g_n\rangle$, it reduces to checking the kernel of the map $\varphi$. I do not know any efficient ways to do this, and suspect that it's difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we could effectively to check that $g_i$ don't satisfy additional relations, then we can decide whether $G\cong H$. But the problem of isomorphism is undecidable.

Comment: In particular, it is unsolvable when $G$ is the trivial group.

Comment: @Derek Holt: Yes, of course.

Comment: Of course, if we know that $H$ and $G$ belong to specific classes of groups, then not all is lost!

Comment: @ user1729: For example, if they are Abelian :-)

Comment: @BorisNovikov: Is there an algorithm in the abelian case or do we just know that it is a decidable problem.

Comment: @Michael Albanese: Maybe these papers are useful to you:

Comment: @Michael Albanese: 
T. Kavitha, Efficient Algorithms for Abelian Group Isomorphism and Related Problems. FST TCS 2003: Foundations of Software Technology and Theoretical Computer Science. Lecture Notes in Computer Science Volume 2914, 2003, pp 277-288.

T. Kavitha, Linear time algorithms for Abelian group isomorphism and related problems. Journal of Computer and System Sciences 73 (2007), pp.986–996.